# how to Use a textfield as a "search bar" for a table view

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiviewcontroller, uitextfield

I have a table view embedded into a regular view (as shown in this picture: [Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QecQl.png))

I have a search bar and working code so that when you start searching for a person's email, the table view automatically updates and just displays the people that match the search criteria.

Is there any way of using a textField in the first view as the search bar?

(if you look at the [Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QecQl.png), then the label that says "para" is where the user is going to type the email of their contact, can I use that label as the search bar, if so, how?)

in other words, how would I use "forField" as the search bar (forField is in the second bit of code)

here is the code for the tableView (currently working):

```
class UsersTableViewController: UITableViewController, UISearchResultsUpdating {
    
    func updateSearchResults(for searchController: UISearchController) {
        //update the search results
        filterContent(searchText: self.searchController.searchBar.text!)
    }
    

    @IBOutlet var usersTableView: UITableView!
    let searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)
    
    var usersArray = [NSDictionary?]()
    var filteredUsers = [NSDictionary?]()
    
    var databaseRef: DatabaseReference!
    
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
 
        searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self
        searchController.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
        definesPresentationContext = true
        
        tableView.tableHeaderView = searchController.searchBar
        
        databaseRef = Database.database().reference()
        let usersRef = databaseRef.child("users")
        let query = usersRef.queryOrdered(byChild: "email")
        query.observe(.childAdded, with: {(snapshot) in
            self.usersArray.append((snapshot.value as? NSDictionary?)!)
            
            //insert the rows
            self.usersTableView.insertRows(at: [IndexPath(row:self.usersArray.count-1, section: 0)], with: UITableView.RowAnimation.automatic)
            
            
        }) { (error) in
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }
        print("HOLAAAAAAAAAAA")
        print(self.usersArray)
        
        // Uncomment the following line to preserve selection between presentations
        // self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = false

        // Uncomment the following line to display an Edit button in the navigation bar for this view controller.
        // self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem
    }

    // MARK: - Table view data source

    override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of sections
        return 1
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of rows
        
        if ((searchController.isActive) && (searchController.searchBar.text != "")){
            return filteredUsers.count
        }
        return self.usersArray.count
    }

    
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)

        let user: NSDictionary
        if ((searchController.isActive) && (searchController.searchBar.text != "")){
            user = filteredUsers[indexPath.row]!
        }else{
            user = self.usersArray[indexPath.row]!
        }

        cell.textLabel?.text = user["email"] as? String
        cell.detailTextLabel?.text = user["name"] as? String
        
        return cell
    }
    
    func filterContent(searchText: String){
        self.filteredUsers =  self.usersArray.filter({ user in
            let userEmail = user!["email"] as? String
            return(userEmail?.lowercased().contains(searchText.lowercased()))!
        })
        
        tableView.reloadData()
    }
    

}
```

and for the view controller it is literally just the text fields and the labels.:

```
class PayViewController: UIViewController, STPAddCardViewControllerDelegate {       
    @IBOutlet weak var forField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var toField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var amountLabel: UILabel!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }
}
```

in other words, how would I use "forField" as the search bar

After recent comments and updates it, I added the following to payViewController:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    //var myTable:UsersTableViewController?
    myTable = self.children[0] as! UsersTableViewController
    self.toField.addTarget(self, action: #selector(UsersTableViewController.textChanges(_:)), for: UIControl.Event.editingChanged)
}
```

and changed the following functions in the table view controller:

```
func updateSearchResults(for searchController: UISearchController) {
        //update the search results
        filterContent(searchText: searchT)
    }

    
    @objc func textChanges(_ textField: UITextField) {
        let text = textField.text! // your desired text here
        // Now do whatever you want.
        searchT = text
    }
```

Comment: Your initial screen can hold the searchController and the TableView can be the SearchResultsController, or just the delegate... UISearchResultsUpdating

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is accessing the child from the parent so you need to declare this inside `PayViewController`

```
var myTable:UsersTableViewController?
```

and inside viewDidLoad

```
myTable = self.children[0] as! UsersTableViewController
```

after that in chnage action of the textfeilds do

```
myTable.filterContent(searchText:forField.text!)
```

Btw you can also transfer the search bar related content inside the `searchController` or to remove that child segue and add a table directly below the fields and make everything inside `PayViewController`

> You don't have to use `UITableViewController` for utilizing table an instance of `UITableView` is sufficient and can be directly as a subview inside the vc

Comment: Hey, Thanks for the answer, would I have to do something about the "updateSearchResults" functions in the table view controller. I have tried what you said, the problem is that it only actually updates it if I use the search bar

Comment: I tried to do that but it tells me Argument of '#selector' refers to instance method 'textChanges' that is not exposed to Objective-C

Comment: add `@objc` before `func`

Comment: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fc2f54324c0'

Comment: please comment the whole crash

Comment: 2019-02-08 15:49:46.583746-0500 Kbuda[30296:1668714] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[Kbuda.PayViewController textChanges:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fa991e22110'

Comment: change this `self.toField.addTarget(self` to `self.toField.addTarget(myTable`

Comment: ok now it doesn't crash anymore! thank you so much.  Now the problem is that it doesn't update unless I search in the bar (it actually searches for what I want it to look for in the toText but it requires me to add info to the searchbar), do you know what to do about that?

Comment: inside `textChanges` do `filterContent(searchText:textField.text!)`

Comment: I did but still same: it actually searches for what I want it to look for in the toText but it doesn't do it until I add text to the search bar. Should I do something about "updateSearchResults"

Comment: you need to remove `if ((searchController.isActive) && (searchController.searchBar.text != "")){` checks that prevents `cellForRowAt` from using the filter array  , you need to define a new active according to the textfeild's text isEmpty or not 
     `

Comment: when you tap on the cell, is it possible to set the textview to that that you just pressed?